# appened custom text to content in template_preprocess_taxonomy_term drupal 8

Tags: hooks

I want to append some custom text to taxonomy term pages using template_preprocess_taxonomy_term hook, But when I add my custom array key to it, the text don't show up on the term pages.
PS I have cleared drupal cache many time.

Here is my code

`function cars_theme_preprocess_taxonomy_term(&$variables) {
      if($variables['view_mode'] == 'full'){
         $variables['content']['cars_view'] = "this is test";
     }
}`

Comment: Your custom key? Did you render that in your template? 
For D8 {{ content.cars_view }}

Comment: No, but if content is being rendered it should render all of the child variables. No?

Comment: Ah now I get it. Under the content key you only can write render arrays , so you need to define your custom key like $variables['cars_view'] and render it {{ cars_view }}.

Comment: Yes, you are right @insasse, I need to render it {{ cars_view }} but I had to add the output outside of content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so here is how I did it.

```
function cars_theme_preprocess_taxonomy_term(&$variables) {
      if($variables['view_mode'] == 'full'){
         $variables['cars_view'] = "this is test";
     }
}
```

And then in my twig file I output the cars_view as {{ cars_view }}